# Margin on custom TextView

Tags: android, textview, margin

I checked a lot of answers, but none helped so far.

I'm trying to extend android's TextView and set the margin of this custom view inside the code, as I'm going to instantiate them on button presses and similar things. It is added to a LinearLayout. That's about what I got:

```
public class ResultsView extends TextView {
    public ResultsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
        setLayoutParams(layout);
    }
}
```

No sign of margin anywhere.

EDIT: I might want to add, if I assign a margin value in xml, it does work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the issue is, that by the time you are trying to add the margin the layoutparams are not set yet, why dont you try overriding this method in your ResultsView class:

```
       protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            MarginLayoutParams margins = MarginLayoutParams.class.cast(getLayoutParams());
            int margin = 15;
            margins.topMargin = margin;
            margins.bottomMargin = margin;
            margins.leftMargin = margin;
            margins.rightMargin = margin;
            setLayoutParams(margins);
        };
```

And remove the code you have in the Constructor, this way the margin will be applied until we are sure we have a layout object for the view, hope this helps

Regards!

Comment: Yay! That really did it, thanks! I actually tried something similar before, but with onFinishInflate, which did not work. Do you know how well this is on the performance side? Should I better add a boolean to check whether we've set it once already?

Comment: I don't think is such a huge performing impact, but if you are concern about it, you can add the flag to do it only once if you want...

Comment: I think you could probably get away with just modifying the dimensions passed into onLayout() (e.g. left += leftMargin, right -= rightMargin, top += topMargin, bottom -= bottomMargin, super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom));

Comment: Does not work with LinearLayout. Probably cuz you never called super.onLayout

Comment: @MartinCazares hi i am getting margins as null...any suggestions?

Comment: `onLayout()` is supposed to set the layout for the view's children not to change the view's own layout. So, this approach will trigger an unnecessary run of the `onLayout` chain and may cause screen flickering (at least on Android 12). It is better to set the margins during `setLayoutParams()` which will be called during view inflation. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @MartinCazares pointed out, the issue is that the layout params are not available in the constructor method and will be overwritten during View inflation. However, it is better to set the margins in `setLayoutParams()` which will be called during View inflation, instead of in `onLayout()`. The latter is supposed to set the layout of the view's children and not change the layout of the view itself. So, changing the layout params there caused screen flickering in my case on Android 12.

My solution:

```
private boolean hasLeftMargin = false;
private boolean hasRightMargin = false;
private boolean hasTopMargin = false;
private boolean hasBottomMargin = false;

public MyView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    // Receive styled attributes
    TypedArray arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] {
            android.R.attr.layout_margin,
            android.R.attr.layout_marginLeft, android.R.attr.layout_marginTop,
            android.R.attr.layout_marginRight, android.R.attr.layout_marginBottom,
            android.R.attr.layout_marginStart, android.R.attr.layout_marginEnd});

    // Check whether margin are assigned in xml (by index of int array above)
    hasLeftMargin = arr.hasValue(0) || arr.hasValue(1) || arr.hasValue(5);
    hasRightMargin = arr.hasValue(0) || arr.hasValue(3) || arr.hasValue(6);
    hasTopMargin = arr.hasValue(0) || arr.hasValue(2);
    hasBottomMargin = arr.hasValue(0) || arr.hasValue(4);
    arr.recycle();
}

@Override
public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (params instanceof MarginLayoutParams) {
        MarginLayoutParams p = (MarginLayoutParams) params;
        if (!hasLeftMargin && p.leftMargin <= 0) p.leftMargin = sideMargin;
        if (!hasRightMargin && p.rightMargin <= 0) p.rightMargin = sideMargin;
        if (!hasTopMargin && p.topMargin <= 0) p.topMargin = verticalMargin;
        if (!hasBottomMargin && p.bottomMargin <= 0) p.bottomMargin = verticalMargin;
    }
    super.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You now need to add this view to the layout which is currently being displayed. You are missing the next step.
So now you need something like :

```
    currentlayout.addview(View);
```

Comment: It is added in XML. I can see the textviews in my LinearLayout, but they have no margin.